# Enforcing DRY: shared code between rjs files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rjs

How do you enforce DRY when you have shared code amongst rjs files?  I'm trying to avoid the duplicated code in [this example](http://pastie.org/623820):

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm...  Could you possibly put the code in a Helper?

Comment: That is exactly what you should do. RJS is just another view and that is where helpers are made to be used.